# Requested resource isn't available (Servlet)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

I created a dynamic web project in `Eclipse` 4.5, called `HelloServlet` and modified `web.xml`. I also added Tomcat 8 in Eclipse. I think I did everything right, but I still can't run the servlet.

In Project explorer: /src/HelloServlet/HelloWorldServlet.java.

HelloWorldServlet.java:

```
package HelloServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorldServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().println("Hello world.");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>HelloServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloServlet.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Sometimes, I get `class not found` without `/HelloWorldServlet`. I searched and knew how to set `servlet-class` correctly, but it still doesn't run.

Comment: can you share your error trace..

Comment: I closed then opened Eclipse. Now, I get: 'starting apache-...' has encountered a problem. Output at console: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException... Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException... Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException... (I can't post all output. It's too long, sorry). I think I did everything correctly, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Stop the server and Clean Tomcat's work directory by right clicking the server

Comment: It didn't work, even after I deleted & recreated the project. It's strange.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in newer versions (I don't know of what. Servlet or Eclipse?), I don't have to add anything to web.xml. `@WebServlet("/HelloWorldServlet")` seems to be enough. I discovered it by trying.

But I noticed strange behavior: While web.xml was modified *as in the question*, I could run the server then get errors *in the browser* like `Reuqested resource isn't available`  or `class not found` exception in `/HelloServlet` & `/HelloServlet/HelloWorldServlet`. After restarting the computer, I couldn't run the server (I think, because of modifying web.xml). I don't remember adding anything new.